# Recursive Replace of Files and Directory names while Preserving the Case

Tags: linux

In Linux, how can I do a recursive replace of files and directory names while preserving the existing case?

So for example, I'm in a directory that has two descendant subdirectories with the names:

```
lastname
Lastname
```

I want to be able to replace them with "lastnamea" and "Lastnamea" respectively.  Basically I want to modify them while preserving the case.  The same goes for files.

Comment: Can you elaborate with an example of before and after?

Comment: @Paul, I just updated the question with an example.

Comment: Hi, can you add another example - because that one is easy to do if it is consistent that the first part of the name remains the same after rename, but I suspect the before and afters are probably more complicated in some instances?

Answer (score 0):

This command will use find to list the absolute path of every file in the directory, and subdirectories. You can use ls to just do the current directory. Xargs performs commands on what is passed in via stdin. -I X says replace X with what was passed in via stdin. If your version of xargs does not have -I, use --replace=X Hope this helps!

find . | xargs -I X mv X Xa